# Attempting to dynamically generate and execute DROP statements using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have php code that parses a directory and generates a SQL statement which checks for the existence of sub directory names as tables in a specific database, and then generates DROP TABLE statements for any that do not exist in the directory:

Directory is called earlier in the code for $DIR.

```
$directories = glob($DIR . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$dir2 = str_replace( "$DIR/"  , ""  , $directories);
$dirlist = implode("', '",$dir2);
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_name, ';') FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'streamer1' AND table_name NOT IN ('$dirlist');";
echo "$sql";
```

This generates a SQL statement in my browser window. When I run the sql statement manually using mysql I get the list of DROP TABLE statements needed for any table names not found as a subdirectory name in the folder.

```
+----------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_name, ';') |
+----------------------------------------+
| DROP TABLE jhtest;                     |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I would like to accomplish is to take these results and execute them in mysql using my php code. I am currently stuck at the point of returning the results in php and then executing each as a mysql statement.

Is this the proper way of generating these drop statements or is there possibly a easier way to edit my sql statement to DROP those tables if not in the provided list (over using CONCAT to generate the drop statements)?

Answer (score 0):

Then just do that:

```
[...]
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_name, ';') FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'streamer1' AND table_name NOT IN ('$dirlist');";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    mysql_query($row[0], $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect to your DB and run the query. Inside the loop the drop statements are executed.

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("information_schema", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_name, ';') as q FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'streamer1' AND table_name NOT IN ('$dirlist');";

//run the query
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$res){
  die(mysql_error());
} else {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo $row['q']."\n"; //output the queries or run the drop statements like this
    mysql_query($row['q']);
  }
}
```